# Question about a question's relevance (Too vague or not specific enough)

Tags: discussion

I'm about to ask a question on [main] StackOverflow that goes something along the lines of "What are the known or unknown pitfalls regarding obsolete code a C# programmer should be aware of?"

What I mean is, through the years, certain things that might have been good practice before, like manually calling the GC garbage collector that aren't anymore because of one reason or another such as C# upgrade to 4.0 making alot of syntax changes etc.

Is this alright? Is it a suitable question for stackoverflow? Or is it too vague? The intention of the question is to clear any doubt one might have with their code when reading on posts pre-2010 StackOverflow.

Comment: see also [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: [Related: best practice zombies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not suitable.

Asking for list of things is off-topic on Stack Overflow as too broad. It is also unlikely suitable for any other Stack Exchange sites.

It may be ok to ask about particular concerns you have with any particular  answer as long as you've researched topic yourself first and made sure it is not covered by existing answers.